# Inherited fields not initialized for child class when inheriting WebForms parent

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm working with a web forms project that has many different sections that have to be set up to be disabled or not depending on user type, status, etc. Because this can be so complicated I wanted to move the logic to an external file. The way I set out to do this was to move the logic into an inherited class and do all my validation there. However when I run any methods from within that class, the elements within the aspx form that are defined within the designer are null. I was wondering if anyone knows what the cause of this is or can recommend a better approach.

```
//ASPX designer page, partial for brevity
public partial class WidgetFactory
{
     // ... One of many elements
     protected global::DevExpress.Web.Bootstrap.BootstrapTextBox tbFirstName;
}

public partial class WidgetFactory: BasePage, IWidgetFactory 
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {
     //Page setup
   }

   protected void SetFormAccessBasedOnConditions() 
   {
       new FormAccessService().SetFormAccess();
   }
}

public class FormAccessService : WidgetFactory 
{
    public void SetFormAccess()
    {
        if(this.OmittedFunctionToRunChecks()) // Runs fine
            base.tbFirstName.Enabled = true;   //Throws a null pointer exception
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no indication in the code shown that `tbFirstName`  is ever initialized/ Re-read the [mre] guidance and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Apologizes, I’ll be able to update the question tomorrow. I’m not super familiar with webforms, I’m guessing the object itself is actually initialized on the aspx form page. It would for sure be initialized by SetFormAccessBasedOnCondition for sure. My thought is I haven’t called the render for my utility class which makes the elements null. Further I think it’d just be a separate page instance making it all pointless

Comment: `SetFormAccessBasedOnConditions()` has only one line of code? What does `FormAccessService().SetFormAccess()` do?

Comment: What does BasePage code look like

Comment: Side note: "I’ll be able to update the question tomorrow" - you probably can just give up now and forget you even tried to ask :) . I'd strongly recommend waiting till you have significant (~an hour) chunk of time when you can immediatly react to feedback/clarification requests to ask a question on SO. If your question falls out from last 50 question on the topic (i.e. C#) the chances anyone ever finds out about it are very low. Result of "Update tomorrow" may be seen for a short time by some people watching for updated questions but will fall out of views very quickly.

Comment: (Note that my comment is extremly rude from SO point of view as it essentially repeats the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you've read. Feel free to flag as such)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, not at all. I appreciate your feedback. That’s good to know about typical exposure for questions. Chetan the BasePage is is just the Page class with some utilities used on various other webform no initialization Basically the crux of what I was trying to do is to externalize some of the tedious logic to other classes to improve maintainability. Doing so through inheritance however I think this is wrong as from my understanding the fields in designer are initialized through the aspx web form, creating a class that inherits from it won’t give me access to that class.

Comment: Things I’ve seen as possible options are making the fields in Form.designer.aspx pubic which I’m not sure how to do and is said to be bad practice. Or to use a method to lookup the form control by its name via string which I’m kind of hesitant to do

Comment: Well, are you inherting that ONE page class then? I mean, that means the new code you create will be 100% tied to that ONE page class - including ONLY properites and methods from that ONE  page class. Each aspx page is in fact a compile time class that gets generated. So, that external code has to inherit not just a "page" class but the specific type and class based on that ONE page name. If the code is to be "general" then you better off to just pass the page class as a object, and not inherit the ONE page class, since then that general class will not be general anymore, will it?

Comment: However, if you pass just the page class, then you have to use page.findControl to get that page object.